# Як правильно вживати слова "говорити", "розмовляти", "мовити", "казати"?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

Коли ці слова правильно вживати? "Говорити" мені здається калькою з російської.

> "Я не говорю по-русски"

але

> "Я не розмовляю українською".

Порівнюючи з польською, я вважаю, що розмова:

- швидка, незрозуміла, неважлива, ні про шо — говорити (gadać)
- розмова звичайна на якусь тему — розмовляти (rozmawiać)
- вимовляти, вживати слова — мовити (mówić)
- наказувати щось зробити, веліти — казати (kazać)

Чи існує чітке визначення правильного вживання зазначених вище слів?

Comment: Я знав, що відшукаю міф про неіснування «говорити» і на цьому сайті :) Слово існує в українській мові, і якщо й слід уникати його, то тільки щоб дати собі можливість застосувати інші його синоніми, які «говорити» перекриває. Схожа історія і з «відкрити», «закрити», які також схильні замінювати собою купу інших слів.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Шановний земляче,

Українське слово "говорити" нічим перед вами не завинило, а ви звинувачуєте його в тому, що це калька. Є цілий шерег українських слів з коренем "гово(і)р": говір, заговір, говірка, говіркий, говорю́чість, позадогові́рний, договір, говорильня тощо.

Щодо вислову "говорити по..." процитую Російсько-український словник сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська)

> - Говорить по-русски, по-украински – *говорити* російською мовою    (по-російськи, по-російському), українською мовою (по-українськи,
>     по-українському).
> - Говорить по душам – говорити щиро (по щирості); говорити відверто.
> - Говорить по поводу чего – говорити з приводу чого.

Російсько-український словник ділової мови 1930р. (М. Дорошенко, М. Станиславський, В. Страшкевич)

> Суть – суть, суття; говорить по сути дела – говорити (в су́ті); до
>   суття спра́ви.

---

Щодо "чіткого" визначення та правильного вживання слів раджу почати з [Словника української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/kazaty) (СУМ), наприклад, слово "казати":

> КАЗАТИ,
>
> 1. Передавати словами (думки, почуття тощо); висловлювати, говорити (у 2 знач.).
> 2. Наказувати комусь робити що-небудь.
> 3. перен. Свідчити про що-небудь.

---

Ось вам невеличкий подарунок від мене з синонімами до слова "говорити": вимовляти, віщати, промовляти, прорікати, розмовляти, ректи, казати, висловлюватися, балакати, лопотіти, лопотати, гелготіти, герготати, джеркотіти, дейкати, шварготати, шваркотіти...[далі](https://www.facebook.com/chystamova/posts/500736783415770:0)